# How can I select specific XML nodes in Powershell from multiple node values?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have the following XML syntax and I'm trying to obtain the value in Node ID "2", Row Key "Vol2-3" for now:

```
<nodes>
   <node id="1">
     <store>
        <row key="Vol1-1" value="1a"/>
        <row key="Vol1-2" value="1b"/>
        <row key="Vol1-3" value="1c"/>
        <row key="Vol1-4" value="1d"/>
</store>
</node>
   <node id="2">
     <store>
        <row key="Vol2-1" value="2a"/>
        <row key="Vol2-2" value="2b"/>
        <row key="Vol2-3" value="2c"/>
        <row key="Vol2-4" value="2d"/>
</store>
</node>
   <node id="3">
     <store>
        <row key="Vol3-1" value="3a"/>
        <row key="Vol3-2" value="3b"/>
        <row key="Vol3-3" value="3c"/>
        <row key="Vol3-4" value="3d"/>
</store>
</node>
</nodes>
```

Code:

```
$nodevar=2 
[xml]$XMLDoc=(Get-Content "\..\..somefile.txt")
$value_extract=$XMLDoc.nodes.SelectNodes("node[@id='$nodevar']").store.SelectNodes("row[@key='']")
```

The issue I have is that I'm trying to set my $value_extract variable to pivot from the correct node ID to get to the corresponding row key containing my value. I wrote it in such a way that I'll eventually be using the SelectNodes in a for loop to obtain the values I need for further processing. Is there a good way to write this since I'm pivoting off of the correct node ID as well as the correct row key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your pivot-problem, but this should work, if you just need to get the text value:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "somexml.xml"
$nodevar = "2"
$keyvar = "Vol2-3"
$value_extract=$xml.SelectNodes("/nodes/node[@id='$nodevar']/store/row[@key='$keyvar3']/@value")
```

Comment: Hi Palle Due. I meant to say using $nodevar=2 to move from that specific node value to get to the underlying row key values. Dunno if that explains it better.

Answer (score 0):

Or without using xpath syntax:

```
$node = $XMLDoc.nodes.node | ? id -eq '2'
$row = $node.store.row | ? key -eq 'Vol2-3'
$row.value
```

Comment: Thanks Swonkie, I'll have to look into this.